# I have 2 slots of ram in my motherboard, can i mix one 2GB and another 4GB ram cards in a windows XP PC?

Tags: windows-xp, memory, motherboard

Actually i have a PC which was build long ago(not too long though probably in 2008), i have 2 slots for the RAM cards and i already have one 2 GB in it,MY question is that can i mix the existing 2 GB with the 4 GB does it actually support the functioning of the PC?

Comment: Thing is you probably won't be able to utilize the 4GB RAM stick alone fully: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_xp : Of course you can be using one the quirky 64-bit XPs or you may want to do some hacking to enable PAE on your 32-bit XP.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether your XP is 32-bit or 64-bit. If you have 32-bit, then it can handle a maximum of 4 GB RAM, so put 4 GB piece and take 2 GB out. If you have 64-bit, then you can use both pieces.

Answer (score 1):

In a 32bit architecture, Windows can address maximum 3GB of memory. In order to use all 6 GB of main memory you should install a 64bit Windows XP. 
Otherwise remaining 3 GB RAM will not be able to used.

In addition to this, if the clock frequencies of the memory modules are different they will work at the slower one's frequency.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the memory limits and the running at the slower clock frequency (beware--I've seen a board that didn't do this, but rather simply looked at the first chip.  Horribly unstable if you didn't have the slowest chip in slot #1 and we didn't know we had mixed speeds!) there's also the problem that if it works at all you'll be degraded to single chip speed rather than using them as a bank.  (Note that if you have only one chip in there now that's the speed you're getting anyway.)